# How to get the store state in Effects using withLatestFrom operator

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm trying with this

```
payloadToBeSaved$ = createEffect(() =>  this.actions$
.ofType(SOME_ACTION)
.withLatestFrom(this.store$)
.map(([action: Action, storeState: AppState]) => {
   // Do something ...
});
```

But this.actions$ is an observable and I have to use this.actions$.pipe().... 
when I try with pipe() all lines red with errors. Don't know how to fix.

Comment: Did you try to to use a specific selector within the withLatestFrom operator: withLatestFrom(this.store$.getUserId()). And you should use the pipe if you are using RxJS 5.5 or newer

Answer (score 2):

```
@Effect()
shipOrder = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<ShipOrder>(ActionTypes.ShipOrder),
  map(action => action.payload),
  concatMap(action =>
    of(action).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(store.pipe(select(getUserName)))
    )
  ),
  map([payload, username] => {
    ...
  })
)
```

Reference: [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#4-using-a-selector-inside-your-effects)